# Lua keyboard/mouse macro - stop on key release

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Good Morning,

I recorded a macro for Logitech Gaming software for my mouse, which is a combination of keyboard presses, left mouse clicks and delays and it works beautifully. It's set to repeat as long as I press a mouse button.

However the problem that I'm having is once I release the button, it doesn't right away end. It finishes the sequence and then ends.

I have no lua coding experiences what so ever and did some googling. I found a lot of info and code to do what I am currently doing, like this one:

```
local flag

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      flag = not flag
      if flag then
         repeat
            -----------------------
            -- your actions here 
            OutputLogMessage("repeat\n")
            Sleep(1000)
            -----------------------
            Sleep(15)
            local prev_flag = flag
            flag = IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
         until not prev_flag and flag
      end
   end
end
```

but if I understand this correctly, it does not interrupt the code if I let go of my mouse button, it simply doesn't loop it again. To give an example, if the code presses 1,2,3,4,5 and I let the button go while it's pressing 3.. I don't want it to do 4,5 - in case that makes any sense.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Tri

Comment: The code you have posted is made for toggling: you press MB#5 to start the loop and later you again press MB#5 to stop this loop.  Your problem (play macro while button is down) can not be solved by this script.  You need another script.

Comment: `It finishes the sequence and then ends.` - This is how LGS macro works.  To immediately stop sequence you need a script.

Comment: So, what do you prefer: "play macro while button is down" or "press-to-start and press-again-to-stop"?

Comment: Hey, yes I understand that LGS macro's work that way, hence me reaching out for help with a script :3 And I prefer "play macro while button is down" please and thank you. Appreciate your time

Answer (score 1):

Create your macro "which is a combination of keyboard presses, left mouse clicks and delays".
I assume the name of your macro is `MY_LOOP`.
Set type of your macro to `toggle`.
Do not bind your macro to any button.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 20 then
      PlayMacro("MY_LOOP")
   end
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 20 then
      AbortMacro()
   end
end
```

The macro works while MB#20 is down.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting this together. Of course noob me has troubles making it fire :D I put your code into the script of my game profile and it saved fine.. cool.

The macro I had recorded with the gaming software is called "Sorc", so I replaced MY_LOOP with Sorc. I don't know which my button 5 is, I have a G600 with 20 buttons. I tried G20 as "20", but that didn't do anything. Sorry to be a pest

Comment: Answer updated.  Now the macro is controlled by button #20.

Comment: That fires now, thank you very much. However when I let go of the button, the line AbortMacro("Sorc") gets highlighted in red and it says "Invalid argument count". The macro is set to toggle.

Comment: Ah.. never mind, I figured it out. AbortMacro () rather than AbortMacro ("Sorc") works. thank you so much for your help with this!

Comment: Ops!.  My fault.